# TextInput allow only numbers react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using `TextInput` to allow only numbers using state, it works on android but not on iOS. Here's how I'm using state to allow only numbers.

```
handleInputChange = (text) => {

  if (/^\d+$/.test(text) || text === '') {
    this.setState({
      text: text
    });
  }
}
```

my render method

```
render = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 0,
      flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        marginTop: 50
    }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, marginLeft: 10 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20}}>$</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1,}}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={this.handleInputChange}
          value={this.state.text}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          autoCorrect={false}
          spellCheck={false}
          style={{ paddingLeft: 5, fontSize: 20 }} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]

This only works in Android, I guess because the state has changed react doesn't update the ui.

Comment: It's been a known bug since long, you can check [TextInput value can't be change during onChangeText - iOS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18874)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ravi Rupareliya said this's a bug, which `TextInput` doesn't update, when the state text is shorter than the current TextInput value. Seems like the bug has been fixed in `react-native 0.57.RC`. For now I'm using the following fix.

```
handleInputChange = (text) => {

    const filteredText = text.replace(/\D/gm, '');

    if(filteredText !== text) {
      // set state text to the current TextInput value, to trigger
      // TextInput update.
      this.setState({ text: text });

      // buys us some time until the above setState finish execution
      setTimeout(() => {

        this.setState((previousState) => {
          return {
            ...previousState,
            text: previousState.text.replace(/\D/gm, '')
          };
        });

      }, 0);
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: filteredText });
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

pls try this:

1. `keyboardType='numeric'` in the tag `TextInput`
2. when you prove don't put the numbers with the keyboard of your pc, pls use the keyboard of the emulator
3. if still not working put this `textContentType='telephoneNumber'`

Comment: Yes, but the numeric keyboard has a `.` and I don't want it to be entered.

Comment: you can auto remove it with the onchangetext , if is only . the trouble would be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

React native not provided keyboardType which remove punctuation from keyboard. You need to use regular expression with replace method to remove punctuation from text and set `keyboardType = 'numeric'`.

**Regular Expression**

> /[- #*;,.<>{}[]/]/gi

**Example code**

```
 onTextChanged(value) {
    // code to remove non-numeric characters from text
    this.setState({ number: value.replace(/[- #*;,.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '') });
  }
```

Please check snack link

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/1e004c

Comment: You might not want to remove "." since it could be float point, but you still need handle dots in case there is ".."

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
<TextInput 
   ...
   textContentType='telephoneNumber' 
   dataDetectorTypes='phoneNumber' 
   keyboardType='phone-pad'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

While having input from user you can change the keyBoard type for that particular text input box like this i.e. numeric or alphabatic etc...

```
<TextInput>
  //contains some code
  keyboardType="Numeric"
</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextInput>
  keyboardType="number-pad"
</TextInput>
```

Comment: Why do you prefer `number-pad` over `numeric`, as suggested in the accepted answer?

Comment: I think number-pad ll not accept special characters or alphabets in keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
onChangeText={value => setuserPrimaryPhone(value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))}
```

javascript simple method `replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))}`